# use json data in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have a model that has one class that is made up of a number of others using OneToOneField.  **My ultimate goal is to be able to loop over a data structure in an abstract way (without using field names) and output the contents to my template using template tags.**  I would like to provide my template with nested data in json format and parse the json using template tags directly in my template.  I have made some use of the Django rest framework.  The following is a generic example of my codebase:

```
models.py--------------------------------------

from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers


class Class1(models.Model):
    class_1_field_1 = models.CharField()
    class_1_field_2 = models.CharField()


class Class2(models.Model):
    class_2_field_1 = models.CharField()
    class_2_field_2 = models.CharField()


class MainClass(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField()
    field_2 = models.IntegerField()
    field_3 = models.DateTimeField()

    class_1 = models.OneToOneField(Class1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    class_2 = models.OneToOneField(Class2, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)


class Class1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Class1
        fields = ('class_1_field_1', 'class_1_field_2')


class Class2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Class2
        fields = ('class_2_field_1', 'class_2_field_2')


class MainClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class_1= Class1Serializer()
    class_2= Class2Serializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MainClass
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'class_1', 'class_2')


views.py-------------------------------------

from django.views.generic import ListView
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from MyApp.models import MainClass, MainClassSerializer


MainClassListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'mainclasses'
    model = MainClass
    serializer_class = MainClassSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        object_list = MainClass.objects.filter(user__in=[self.request.user])
        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        serializer = MainClassSerializer(MainClass.objects.filter(user__in=[self.request.user]), many=True)
        context['data'] = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
        return context

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MainClassListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


index.html----------------------------------------------------

...

{{data}}

...

json output-------------------------------------------------------

b'[{
   "field_1": "Some String",
   "field_2": 100,
   "field_3": "2020-04-20T02:34:27.912451Z",
   "class_1": {
      "class_1_field_1": "str_1",
      "class_1_field_2": "str_2"
   },
   "class_2": {
      "class_2_field_1": "str_3",
      "class_2_field_2": "str_4"
   }
}]'
```

The `{{data}}` tag displays a string (see above) with the following format: `b'[valid_json_is_displayed_here]'`, where the `valid_json_is_displayed_here` is a properly formatted json structure that includes the nested data from the OneToOneField relationships.

I would like to parse the individual values in the returned json output in template tags directly in my template including the one-to-one relationship data.  Is this possible in Django and how can I accomplish this?  I feel like it should be simple, what am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply pass `MainClass` instance into template, and access fields like `mainClassInstance.class_1.class_1_field1` in template. Simpler, cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Django template can parse `dict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) with dot notation.

So, if you add a `dict` to `context`, it'll make parsing very easy.

```
import json

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        serializer = MainClassSerializer(MainClass.objects.filter(user__in=[self.request.user]), many=True)
        context['data'] = json.loads(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data))
        return context
```

And in template:

```
{% for d in data %}
    {{ d.field1}}
    {{ d.class_1.class_1_field_1}}
{% endfor %}
```

But instead of doing this, you can simply pass `MainClass` instance into template, and access fields like `mainClassInstance.class_1.class_1_field1` in template.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['data'] = MainClass.objects.filter(user__in=[self.request.user])
        return context
```

And in template:

```
{% for d in data %}
    {{ d.field1}}
    {{ d.class_1.class_1_field_1}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, @narendra-choudhary.  One of the issues I face is to loop over all of the data that is returned in a very generic fashion and output it to the UI using tags.  I can see I didn't make that clear in my question.  Do you have an idea of how I can accomplish that with the "model" solution that you proposed?  I am under the impression this would be easier to accomplish with the json structure.  Do you have an opinion on this?  I would not be able to access fields by name, only through an "abstract" loop  ({% for x in data %}, or by index somehow, etc.).

Comment: <I would not be able to access fields by name...> You will be able to access fields by name. `data` resolves to `QuerySet` of `MainClass` model. `QuerySet`s are iterable, so `d` in `for` loop resolves to a `MainClass` object. You can then access all fields of this object (including `OneToOneField`s) using `.` notation.

Comment: Yes, that is true - you are right.  :)  What I am saying is that I have a LOT of data and in a practical way, I do not want to be entering every field name into my page in order to get the data displayed.  It is absolutely true that I can get the data that way, but for my purposes I need a more abstract solution.  Sorry I was not more clear on that.  Thank you for continuing to work this problem with me.  :)

Comment: You want something like `{{ d.class_1 }}` to render JSON representation for related `Class1` instance? This will avoid listing all fields of `Class1` in template.

Comment: With the change you suggested, my return from `{{data}}` is now:  `[{
   "field_1": "Some String",
   "field_2": 100,
   "field_3": "2020-04-20T02:34:27.912451Z",
   "class_1": {
      "class_1_field_1": "str_1",
      "class_1_field_2": "str_2"
   },
   "class_2": {
      "class_2_field_1": "str_3",
      "class_2_field_2": "str_4"
   }
}]`;  I tried to use `{% for k, v in data.items %}` but nothing is coming out - literally there is nothing returned.  How do I get the data out of this structure?  It looks as if I have a dict with a single value that is a json structure...

Comment: For `{% for k, v in data.items %}`  to render anything, `data` must be a Python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). `data.item` in  `{% for k, v in data.items %}` is actually a [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) call.

Comment: In example I suggested, `data` in template is a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api). `QuerySet` does not have any `items()` method, or `item` attribute.